# Validate JSON against Objection model

Tags: javascript, json, objection.js

I have a model like

```
export default MyModel extends Model {
   id!: string;
   name!: string;
   age!: number;
   classes: Classes;

    public static tableName = 'users';
    public static columnNameMappers = snakeCaseMappers();

    static get jsonSchema(): JSONSchema {
       return {
            type: 'object',
            required: ['name', 'age'], 
            properties: {
                id: { type: 'string', format: 'uuid', readOnly: true },
                name: { type: 'string' },
                age: { type: 'integer', minimum: 0 },
                classes: {
                     type: 'object',
                     required: ['className', 'instructorId']
                     properties: {
                         className: { type: 'string' },
                         instructorId: {type: 'string', format: 'uuid'}
                     }
                 }
              }
          }
     }
}
```

Somewhere else I have a function to validate that some object I have matches this schema.

```
function validateSubscriptionConfiguration(myJson) {
    return ??;
}
```

Is there a straightforward way to do this in Objection or in Javascript in general? Or do I have to use some packages to achieve this?

Comment: Objection.js has a `$validate` method and also can do validation by default: https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/guide/validation.html#examples.